# Spurious SocketException

Tags: visual-studio-code, exception, windows-10, .net-6.0, http-status-code-500

I've suddenly started getting this exception when running a `net6` application in `VSCode`:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

```
HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:51351)
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(string host, int port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

When I look in the `VSCode` debug console I see this:

```
Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/ - - - 500 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 4247.6422ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/ - - - 500 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 4247.6422ms
```

The application was previously working just fine and I made no changes to the code since the last good run when this problem started.
 
I cannot see anything in Windows Defender Firewall which would indicate a blocked port and nothing in the application references `port 51351` which regularly changes when the application is restarted.

When I run `Test-NetConnection 127.0.0.1 -Port 5000` I get:

```
WARNING: TCP connect to (127.0.0.1 : 5000) failed
 

ComputerName           : 127.0.0.1
RemoteAddress          : 127.0.0.1
RemotePort             : 5000
InterfaceAlias         : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
SourceAddress          : 127.0.0.1
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

What should I be looking for to identify the source of this problem?

Can anyone tell me what is responsible for the `localhost:51351` part of the output? I do not have that configured anywhere and it changes each time I rebuild and restart the app.